# How to correctly use clear(), evict() and close() methods in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have read more information about these commands but didn't understand exactly what a right way to use these commands?.

I want to discover deeply the difference between `clear()`, `evict()` and `close()` methods in details. As I know `evict()` will clear particular object from session in hibernate and `clear()` will clear all objects from session.

How to use them correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Approximately the definition of the commands:

`Clear ()`:  When this method get called inside transaction boundry then all objects which are currently associate with particular session will be  disconnected / clean or no longer associate with that Session instance.
Therefore, after calling this method nothing will be performed on persistance layer or DB.

`Evict()`:  Removes the object from the session. This method is used to dissociate/disconnect the specified object from the session.

`Close()` : Close session by calling `session.close()` method, means End the session and releasing the JDBC Connection and clean up.

Examples of using these commands you can find [here](https://www.connect2java.com/tutorials/hibernate/clear-evict-and-close-methods-in-hibernate/).

Comment: If the requirement is to remove the **specific** object from the session Cache, in that case we could use **evict(ob)**

Comment: @Kms, Yes, it is true.